# Facebook API redirect to wrong place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$facebook = new Facebook($configs);
$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if($uid) {
    // Do stuffs
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

    echo('<script> top.location.href = "' . $loginUrl . '";</script>');
}
?>
```

All work perfectly, but, if user are not logged, the script redirect to Facebook which ask login. When login, the script redirect to my application external url `http://mywebsite.com/facebook-app` and not my `apps.facebook.com/myappid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the URLs on the apps settings page on Facebook Developer are correct. If your app is of the  'App on Facebook' type, check that

```
Canvas URL
Secure Canvas URL
```

are correct.

If it's a 'Mobile Web' app, check

```
Mobile Web URL
```

and so on depending on the type of app.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `$loginUrl`:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'next'=>'http://apps.facebook/myappid'
));
```

Haven't encountered this problem in particular, but this might be of use !